# How to turn off error in mouseover and mouseout events

Tags: angular, events, mouseevent

I am new at Angular and have got one Error, that I can not handle by my own. I want to set mouseover and mouseout events on elements. My code is working properly, but in console I have this Error on every pixel of move:

#### AppComponent.html:108 ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.###

I suppose it happens because of multy calling of mouseover event.

Here is my code.

```
@ViewChild('browser_left', {static:true}) private leftElement: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('browser_center', {static:true}) private centerElement: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('browser_right', {static:true}) private rightElement: ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.leftPicture = this.leftElement.nativeElement;
    this.centerPicture = this.centerElement.nativeElement;
    this.rightPicture = this.rightElement.nativeElement;
}

@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event.target'])
onMouseMove(event) {
```

**Here is my .html file:**

```
<div class="browser_pictures" (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)">
    <img src="../assets/img/browser-left.png" alt="" class="browser_left" id="browser_left" #browser_left >
    <img src="../assets/img/browser-center.png" alt="" class="browser_center" id="browser_center" #browser_center >
    <img src="../assets/img/browser-right.png" alt="" class="browser_right" id="browser_right" #browser_right >
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both document and div have the same event bound to the same event handler, but for one you're sending $event, and for another you're sending $event.target.

Comment: Yes, you were write. Thanks, bro!